# First-order perturbation of a spring with some stiffness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I am learning about perturbation theory in ODE. I have the ODE 
$$\ddot{y}(t) + \alpha \epsilon \dot{y}(t) + y(t) = 0,\\y(0) = y_0\neq 0\\ \dot{y}(0) = 0,$$

where $\epsilon>0$ is small. (This admits an exact solution, i.e.
$$y(t,\epsilon) = y_0e^{-\alpha\epsilon/2}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^2\epsilon^2}{4}}t\right) + \frac{\alpha \epsilon}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^2\epsilon^2}{4}}}\sin\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^2\epsilon^2}{4}}t \right) \right)$$
but the idea is to practice the perturbation method.)

I convert the system into a first-order vector ODE:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\eta(t,\epsilon)=
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
0&-1\\
1 & -\alpha \epsilon
\end{matrix}
\right]
\eta(t,\epsilon)=A(\epsilon)\eta(t,\epsilon)
 $$
To determine that approximation up to first order, I claim that the first term is $y_0\cos(t)$. To determine the coefficient $\phi_1(t)$ on $\epsilon$, I note that $\phi_1(t)$ must solve
$$
\dot{\phi}_1(t) = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}A(\epsilon)\eta(t,\epsilon)\right|_{\epsilon = 0}\\
=A(0)\dot{\phi}_1(t) + A'(0)
\left(
y_0 \left[
\begin{matrix}
 \cos(t)\\\sin(t)
\end{matrix}
 \right]
\right).
$$
If I solve this, I get
$$
\phi_1(t) = \frac{y_0}{2}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\alpha t \cos(t) - (a+2t)\sin(t)\\
2t\cos(t) -\alpha t \sin(t)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
giving an approximation
$$\eta(t,\epsilon)=y_0\cos(t) + \frac{y_0}{2}\left( \alpha t \cos(t) - (\alpha + 2t) \sin(t)\right)\epsilon + o(\epsilon).$$

However, Wolfram keeps telling me that 
$$\left. \frac{\partial y(t,\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon = 0} = \frac{\alpha y_0}{2}(\sin(t) - \cos(t)),$$
where $y(t,\epsilon)$ is the exact solution. So I am now wondering if I am making a concepual error, or a computational error (I've checked my computation a few times, but of course there could still be an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=\frac{\partial y}{\partial\epsilon}$. The original equation, when differentiated with respect to $\epsilon$, becomes
$$
          w''+\alpha \epsilon w'+w=-\alpha y',\\ w(0)=w'(0)=0.
$$
You know that $y|_{\epsilon=0}=y_{0}\cos t$. So $w|_{\epsilon=0}$ solves
$$
                   z''+z=\alpha y_{0}\sin t,\\ z(0)=z'(0)=0,
$$
which has solution
$$
              z(t)= -\frac{1}{2}\alpha y_{0}t\cos t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha y_{0}\sin t=\frac{1}{2}\alpha y_{0}(\sin t-t\cos t).
$$
Did you drop a $t$ when you transcribed from Wolfram?

Comment: I did drop a $t$! Unfortunately, it won't compute when I include the $t$. I agree with your answer, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than convert to a first order system, you may plug a Taylor approximation in the nonlinear system and group terms by powers of $\epsilon$.  For the DE here, 
assume a solution of the form:
\begin{equation*}
\phi(t) = \phi_{0}(t) + \phi_{1}(t)\epsilon + O(\epsilon^{2})
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{alignat*}{2}
y^{\prime\prime}+\alpha\epsilon+y &= 0 &&\Rightarrow \\
\phi_{0}^{\prime\prime}(t) + \phi_{1}^{\prime\prime}(t)\epsilon
+\alpha\epsilon(\phi_{0}^{\prime}(t) + \phi_{1}^{\prime}(t)\epsilon)
+\phi_{0}(t) + \phi_{1}(t)\epsilon
&= 0 &&\Rightarrow
\end{alignat*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\phi_{0}^{\prime\prime}(t) + \phi_{0}(t) &= 0\\
\phi_{1}^{\prime\prime}(t)+\alpha\phi_{0}^{\prime}(t)+\phi_{1}(t) &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Solving the first equation and then applying the initial condition gives:
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{0}(t) = y_{0}\cos(t)
\end{equation*}
This compares to your exact equation when $\epsilon = 0$.
For the second equation, we now have
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{1}^{\prime\prime}(t)+\phi_{1}(t) = \alpha y_{0}\sin(t)
\end{equation*}
This can be solved by the method of coefficients (which Wolfram is very helpful with).  Doing it by hand, I get
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{1}(t) = y_{0}\left(\sin(t)-t\alpha\cos(t)\right)
\end{equation*}
Conceptually, the important part is that this function is linear in $t$.
Thus, the approximation will deviate over time which is why it is only accurate in a local neighborhood.
The final perturbed approximation is now
\begin{equation*}
\phi(t) = y_{0}\cos(t) + y_{0}\left(\sin(t)-t\alpha\cos(t)\right)\epsilon + O(\epsilon^{2}).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Isn't the second equation $\phi_1''(t)+\phi_1(t)=\alpha y_0\sin(t)$ though? Otherwise where is the $y(t)$ term from the original equation?

Comment: Yes.  It was a typo, and I corrected it.  Sorry, about that.